# Can't send emails when website is publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, office365, email

I manage my emails through Office 365 through GoDaddy as my hosting. My email form was able to send when it is local but when I publish the website, I run into this configuration error. I used the appropriate SMTP settings for Office 365. Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance.
[image]

**An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried viewing the page with custom errors set to true? as is no one can answer this question to figure out the error.

Comment: Just try this link. May be it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377599/gmail-smtp-getting-error-with-godaddy

Comment: When I set it customer error to true, it just shows me a default configuration error page with no details on the errors @JustAnotherDotNetDev

Comment: Thank you @Pramod! That works!